# wxTreeCtrl which contains wxCheckBox element. Is it possible?

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython, wxwidgets

I've got to do wxTreeCtrl which contains wxCheckBox elements. Similar like that you can see in different installers. You can select several elements, all elements and etc.

Is it possible?

When I can see some examples?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [CustomTreeCtrl](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.lib.agw.customtreectrl-module.html) can do it. An example is in the [wxPython demo](http://www.wxpython.org/download.php#stable).